# Access Remote PC Registry from Remotely-Started Process

Tags: c#, registry, processstartinfo

Let's say my PC is A, and a remote one is B. Both are windows machines.

From A I start an executable that is on a shared location in PC B. Using the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes.

When the remote process tries to access the registry, it access PC A's registry, even though it runs on B.

I understand this is because I run the process from PC A remotely, but how can I access PC B's registry instead?

I've tried setting ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile to true, no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it would run on B just because the file is located there? B might e.g. be a Linux machine.

Comment: Both are windows machine, added to the question.

Comment: even if the exe is launched from a remote location, it will be a running process on the machine that executed it (PC A in your case) in the memory of the machine that executed it. It would be insecure to allow processes to access another machine other than the one that launched it. Depending on your needs, you may consider PowerShell remoting for accessing remote machines

Comment: Does not matter. You are loading a file from B into A's memory and starting it there. Imagine the security implications if it were the way you suppose.

Comment: I understand, I will have to use a different approach then. Thank you both for good answers.

Comment: You need to either use remote registry to access B's registry when running on A, or you can use [SysInternals psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) command to execute the program on B.